# C++ EventHandler Class

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, event-handling

I need to have some thread-safe event handler (like C#'s `EventHandler`), so I made one. Here is my event handler class and sample code (compiled with VS2013). Is this code OK to be operated in multithreaded environment?

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <atomic>
#include <list>
#include <conio.h>

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Event Handler class

template <typename _EventArg>
class EventHandler
{
public:
    EventHandler()
    {
        m_flag.clear();
    }

    EventHandler(const EventHandler& other)
    {
        m_flag.clear();
        m_ptr = other.m_ptr;
    }

    EventHandler& operator= (const EventHandler& other)
    {
        m_flag.clear();
        m_ptr = other.m_ptr;
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~EventHandler()
    {
        while (m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
    }

    template <typename _Type>
    EventHandler(void (_Type::*memFn)(_EventArg), _Type *obj)
    {
        m_flag.clear();
        m_ptr.reset(new std::function<void(_EventArg)>(std::bind(memFn, obj, std::placeholders::_1)));
    }

    void operator() (_EventArg e)
    {
        while (m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
        if (m_ptr.get()) { (*m_ptr)(e); }
        m_flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }

    bool operator== (const EventHandler& other)
    {
        while (m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
        bool equal = (m_ptr == other.m_ptr);
        m_flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
        return equal;
    }

private:
    std::atomic_flag m_flag;
    std::shared_ptr<std::function<void(_EventArg)>> m_ptr;
};

template <typename _Type>
class IEvent
{
public:
    IEvent()
    {
        m_flag.clear();
    }

    virtual ~IEvent()
    {
        while (m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
    }

    void operator+= (const EventHandler<_Type>& handler)
    {
        while (m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
        m_list.push_back(handler);
        m_flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }

    void operator-= (const EventHandler<_Type>& handler)
    {
        while (m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
        m_list.remove(handler);
        m_flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }

    void operator() (_Type arg)
    {
        while (m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
        for (auto& f : m_list) { f(arg); }
        m_flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }

private:
    std::atomic_flag m_flag;
    std::list<EventHandler<_Type>> m_list;

    // make non-copyable
    IEvent(const IEvent&);
    IEvent& operator= (const IEvent&);
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Event source class
class CSource {
public:
    void RaiseEvent(int value)
    {
        MyEvent(value); // Raise event
    }

    IEvent<int> MyEvent;
};

// Event receiver class
class CReceiver {
public:
    void MyHandler1(int e)
    {
        printf("CReceiver::MyHandler1 called with value %d\n", e);
    }

    void MyHandler2(int e)
    {
        printf("CReceiver::MyHandler2 called with value %d\n", e);
    }
};

void main()
{
    CSource source;
    CReceiver receiver;

    // define event handler
    EventHandler<int> handler1 = EventHandler<int>(&CReceiver::MyHandler1, &receiver);
    EventHandler<int> handler2 = EventHandler<int>(&CReceiver::MyHandler2, &receiver);

    // add event handler
    source.MyEvent += handler1;
    source.MyEvent += handler2;

    // raise event with value 1234!
    source.RaiseEvent(1234);

    // remove event handler
    source.MyEvent -= handler1;
    source.MyEvent -= handler2;

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: any reason for not using a proper mutex in favor of a busy loop lock?

Comment: @ratchetfreak I heard atomic_flag is faster than mutex, so i used atomic_flag.

Answer (score 3):

**RAII**

Whenever you need to acquire a resource, hold it for a while, and then release it deterministically - think resource acquisition is initialization. RAII! When I look at your equality comparison:

```
bool operator== (const EventHandler& other)
{
    while (m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
    bool equal = (m_ptr == other.m_ptr);
    m_flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    return equal;
}
```

We're really doing two things. We're acquiring and releasing a lock on `m_flag`, and then we're doing the equality comparison. So let's make that a lot more explicit.

[`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) is an RAII lock, templated on a [`BasicLockable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BasicLockable) - which is just a class that supports a `lock()` and `unlock()`. So instead of holding a `std::atomic_flag` member, we can hold a member of type:

```
struct FlagMutex {
    void lock() {
        while (m_flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
    }

    void unlock() {
        m_flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    }

    /*
     * note that you were not initializing your flag correctly!
     */
    std::atomic_flag m_flag = ATOMIC_INIT_FLAG;
};
```

And then our equality operator becomes:

```
bool operator== (const EventHandler& other) {
    std::lock_guard<FlagMutex> lk(m_mutex);
    return m_ptr == other.m_ptr;
}
```

Keep that in mind throughout. Furthermore, if you do it this way, then `FlagMutex` can become a template argument for `EventHandler` so you can actually test the assertion that a `std::atomic_flag` is faster than a `std::mutex`.

**Generalize Your Class**

Right now, your event handler is constructible with:

```
template <typename _Type>
EventHandler(void (_Type::*memFn)(_EventArg), _Type *obj)
```

But why limit to *just* member functions? Your class has a `std::function` member. That can support free functions. Just generalize it.

Additionally, prefer [`make_shared` to just `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20895648/difference-in-make-shared-and-normal-shared-ptr-in-c):

```
using FuncType = std::function<void(_EventArg)>;

template <typename F,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
              std::is_constructible<FuncType(F&&)>::value
          >>
EventHandler(F&& func)
{
    m_ptr = std::make_shared<FuncType>(std::forward<F>(func));
}
```

The user can pass in a bind expression if they want, or a lambda, or any number of other things. Just lets you do more things.

Also `_EventArg` is a reserved name.

Comment: Thx for reply. // i heard std::function doesn't support compare operator(only for nullptr)... so i used shared_ptr for comparison.

Comment: @ooo0o Ah, good point, lemme fix that part.